# How to know if my server is using SSL or not (with Twisted)

Tags: python, ssl, tcp, twisted

I've wrote a simple client and a server.
They both can configured to use SSL or not. You can set it up in the client and in the server.
My problem is, if I try to connect without SSL to a server setup with SSL, the connection is made but stuck. (of course... it is normal).
How my client can know that he is trying to connect without SSL to a server using SSL? and vice versa?

The best solution will be that my client autodetect if server use SSL or not and do the proper connect(TCP or SSL).

Thans in advance for any answer =)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why haven't you ever accepted an answer to your questions? At time of writing, you have asked 8 questions and never voted on anything or marked an answer. Have you read the FAQ on asking questions on this site?

Comment: simple, you must register and I don't want to. Do you want to ask me why I don't have facebook or twitter or ... ? thanks =)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "register"... you've got a username already. All you have to do it click the "check" next to an answer to accept it.

Comment: ahhh I just discover that check and vote are not the same thing! when i want to vote it ask me to register, not when i check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different port number for SSL connections. This is how HTTP / HTTPS are used.

Or

Define a command in your protocol to transform the connection into SSL e.g. `STARTTLS`, based on a capability negotiation. This is one way the same thing is achieved in SMTP.

Comment: Using different ports is not a good idea since ports can be change in server's config. I was thinking about STARTTLS, but it's not really what I want. It will fix the problem about connection stuck when client is using ssl and server not (and vice versa), but it will force the client to connect as the server want (ssl or not). I'll think about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The best solution will be that my client autodetect if server use SSL
>   or not and do the proper connect(TCP or SSL).

Not possible. The first event in an SSL connection is a message from the client, not from the server.

Comment: `Not possible` is perhaps overstating the case. For example, if you define a protocol that uses [DNS-based service discovery](http://files.dns-sd.org/draft-cheshire-dnsext-dns-sd.txt), a client could determine whether or not secure implementations of the protocol were available.

Comment: I must take a look at this. Thanks.